# Reclassifying vectorlayer attribute-column using dictionary in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, geopandas

I am new to working in QGIS-python environment, and I am trying to create a QGIS-plugin, where i want to create a new attributetable-column on a vector-layer based on some choices done by a user. A reclassifier so to say

So using GeoPandas, I would have collected the translation information in a dictionary with old information on left side, and the new information on the right. like

```
dictionary = {
        'old_data1' : 'new_data1',
        'old_data2' : 'new_data2',
        'old_data3' : 'new_data3',
    }
```

and then used geopandas .map() to create a new column based on this dictionary:

```
vectorlayer = gpd.read_file('vectorlayer.shp')
vectorlayer['new_class'] = vectorlayer['old_class'].map(dictionary)
```

Which would then create a new column with translated values.

Is there any similar function in the PyQGIS toolbox to use for this maneuver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know of a one-line solution like in pandas.

But you can try:

```
dictionary = {
        'old_data1' : 'new_data1',
        'old_data2' : 'new_data2',
        'old_data3' : 'new_data3'}

layer = iface.activeLayer()
newfieldindex = layer.fields().indexFromName('newfield') #The field needs to be created in advance
attrmap = {} #dictionary of feature id: {field index: new value}
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    if f['asdf'] in dictionary:
        attrmap[f.id()] = {newfieldindex:dictionary[f['asdf']]}

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attrmap)
```

[image]